# PHP + JSON Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, json

I just started using JSON and found this example from http://imdbapi.com/:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// IMDb ID to Search
var imdbLink = "tt1285016";

// Send Request
var http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
http.open("GET", "http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=" + imdbLink, false);
http.send(null);

// Response to JSON
var imdbData = http.responseText;
var imdbJSON = eval("(" + imdbData + ")");

// Returns Movie Title
alert(imdbJSON.Title);

</script>
```

But it just returns a blank page. What is wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using?  the ActiveXObject is (more than likely) IE only.

Comment: i am using internet explorer.

Comment: It works for me on IE9, but it does throw a security error, so your security level might not allow you to run ActiveX.  Joey's next answer, about how to use jQuery is the more modern way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry not to directly answer your question, but here is a jQuery version:

```
var imdbLink = "tt1285016";

// Send Request
$.getJSON("http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=" + imdbLink + "&callback=?", function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

There are a couple possible issues with your code.

1.) ActiveX is IE only, not firefox, chrome, safari, etc.

2.) You have a cross-domain issue.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbZ5b/)